# How can I import my data from Parse? I would like to import data from a user class other than the class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

var users = [""] // *This is a temporary Array for storing the data from Parse.*

```
@IBOutlet var messageTableView: UITableView!
// The TableView will output the data in the array.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        //Delete Array Data..
        for object in objects! {

            var posts:PFUser = object as! PFUser

            self.users.append(posts.username!)
            //and append data to Array.

        }

        self.messageTableView.reloadData()}
```

My question :

This data is loaded from the "Users" class. 
But what I want is to load the data in the "posts" Class, what do you do? This is my first question raised in Stackoverflow. Please take care of me. : -) Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a PFUser object instead of a PFQuery object.

From the parse documentation ([link](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries)):

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        println(object.objectId)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```